# Error: TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, monodevelop, router

I am new to Node Js just started to learn and was trying the following code but there is something wrong in this and it is throwing error.There are similar question available but could not figure out what is wrong in this.

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const logger = require('./middleware/logger')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const passport = require('passport');
var securedRoutes = express.Router();


//set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

securedRoutes.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send('Test!!!Vmal');
})

//Init middleware
app.use(logger);
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"]
    }
}));

app.use(passport);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true,parameterLimit:50000}));
app.listen(PORT,() => console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`));
module.exports = app;
```

Error : throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
    ^TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function.

Can someone please help on this.Thanks

Comment: Which line throw the error ? If its not indicated try to comment each app.use to see which one raise the error

Comment: from app.use(passport); it is throwing the error.

Comment: See answer under

Comment: still getting the same error.app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport);
app.use(cookieParser()); in the second line of this

Comment: you should delete the `app.use(passport)` line

Comment: remove this one : app.use(passport);, and replace it with app.use(passport.initialize())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use `passport` module, you have to **initialize** it when referring from app.

From npm documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport:

```
...
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(cookieParser());
...
```